# MvvmCross Android Navigation Stack

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a ViewModel which calls 3 other ViewModels in return, which has the [NoHistory = true] attribute set on the Views. This works perfectly and the back button does not cause any of those 3 views to show up.

However I have the following Navigation issue: the 1st ViewModel is shown from a ListView, when Close() is called on the 1st ViewModel, the View closes as expected but skips the ListView that called ShowViewModel and shows the View preceding the ListView. Pressing Back takes me to the ListView and then shows the 1st ViewModel again. This only seems to happen when using Close() but not when using the Back Button. The design of the application requires the View to be closed based on Transaction States.

This is now causing all sorts of weirdness, does anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: Post some code, issue can not be found from the story!!

Comment: Adding code won't show the issue since it is standard Mvvmcross Android mechanics. Pressing the back button navigates correctly, calling Close() on the ViewModel skips the ListView and ends up on the 1st View.

Comment: Then hope someone else helps you!!

Comment: Yea you're going to have to provide some code.  Any thing weird in the debug trace?